# How can I get an Android 11 test app to compile

Tags: android, android-11

Trying to test an app in Android 11 (API 30), but it won't compile.

`Error: Module 'app': platform 'android-30' not found`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
```

with:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
```

We will not be able to use `30` until later this year.